# Can't open hadoop localhost:50070

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, localhost

Hi i'm try to install hadoop (single-node) on ubuntu.
I can't open localhost:50070.

When i lunch jps i got this

```
6674 NodeManager
6825 Jps
6359 ResourceManager
```

i'm new on ubuntu so explain as much you can , thanks a lot.

```
daniele@daniele-S551LB:/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin$ ./start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
daniele@localhost's password: 
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-daniele-namenode-daniele-S551LB.out
daniele@localhost's password: 
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-daniele-datanode-daniele-S551LB.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
daniele@0.0.0.0's password: 
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-daniele-secondarynamenode-daniele-S551LB.out
daniele@daniele-S551LB:/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin$ jps
2935 Jps
daniele@daniele-S551LB:/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin$ ./start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
daniele@localhost's password: 
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-daniele-namenode-daniele-S551LB.out
daniele@localhost's password: 
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-daniele-datanode-daniele-S551LB.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
daniele@0.0.0.0's password: 
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-daniele-secondarynamenode-daniele-S551LB.out
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/yarn-daniele-resourcemanager-daniele-S551LB.out
daniele@localhost's password: 
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/yarn-daniele-nodemanager-daniele-S551LB.out
daniele@daniele-S551LB:/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin$ jps
3931 Jps
3846 NodeManager
3529 ResourceManager
```

Comment: can you put here logs?

Comment: Try Step 1)sudo service hadoop-master stop Step2) sudo service hadoop-master start

Comment: after stop & star, send the output of sudo jps

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j6effd533kbpwa7/AABUpPopyOMP5tPadzd0N9qQa?dl=0

I put here all the logs

Comment: Check netstat to see if the port is accepting connection--
netstat -tunlp | grep 50070

Answer (score 1):

Check in the logs if tmp directory is in consistent state

Log file location : $HADOOP_HOME/logs/hadoop-*-namenode-**.log

You might see something in the log file

2016-12-10 00:59:55,718 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /tmp/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.

declare the tmp dir in core-site.xml and then format the namenode.

I hope it'll help you

Answer (score 0):

Check netstat to see if the port is accepting connection--
netstat -tunlp | grep 50070

And where is your namenode running(Can see only YARN Services).. None of HDFS services are running here..

To start HDFS service run commnad - start-dfs.sh

when you do jps you should find below process

14370 SecondaryNameNode

14020 NameNode

14661 NodeManager

14151 DataNode

15003 Jps

14526 ResourceManager

Comment: I tried to stop all service, delete the 'tmp' folder and create it again. Formatted the namenode and start-all.sh / start-dfs.sh .

I got
`6361 SecondaryNameNode`
`7307 Jps`
`7173 NodeManager`

And if i do 
`netstat -tunlp | grep 50070` nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

@daniele, Run all the hadoop services in case if it is not running-

**$ start-all.sh** or

**$ start-dfs.sh** and **$ start-yarn.sh**

Hadoop required server to run the services. You are using the Ubuntu Desktop version. Please make sure you have apache server installed and running.
You can also use other servers for this purpose.

To install the apache server -**$ sudo apt-get install apache2**

Check the status of apache server -**$ sudo service httpd status**

Other way to check whether server is working or not.
 Check the System IP using the following command: 
    **$ ifconfig**

and paste the same IP on your Window/MAC browser. If it working fine, you will get Server information, if it not working, you will connection fail or unknown host error.

**Steps to resolve the issue:**

1. If you don't have any server, please install the server and make sure it is working and enable.
2. Disable the firewall: **$sudo ufw disable** or You can simply allow the port: **$sudo ufw allow 50070**
3. Recreate the HDFS:

   **$ sudo rm -r location_of_HDFS**

   **$ sudo mkdir location_of_HDFS**

   **$ sudo chown hadoop_username location_of_HDFS**
4. Format the namenode:

   **$ hadoop namenode -format**
5. Start the hadoop services:

   **$ start-all.sh** or

   **$ start-dfs.sh** and **$ start-yarn.sh**

Hope this helps. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You have stop all the services. And you have restart the namenode service. Finally start all the service.

```
bin/stop-all.sh
bin/hadoop namenode -format 
bin/start-all.sh
```

If you have execute then, check it namenode.